# Need help in writing Linq Query

Tags: entity-framework, linq

Need help to convert the below SQL Query to Linq Query

```
WITH cteStatus AS(
  SELECT convert(varchar(10), UpdatedDate, 120) as UpdatedDate, Status, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY convert(varchar(10), UpdatedDate, 120), Status ORDER BY UpdatedDate, Status) rn
    FROM Pipeline
 )
SELECT Top 1 c.UpdatedDate
  FROM cteStatus c
  WHERE Status = N'SUCCESS'     AND rn = 3
  ORDER BY c.UpdatedDate DESC
```

Comment: Why do you need it converted to Linq? You can run direct SQL queries in most frameworks. Perhaps a  better approach is to start with the _results_ that you need rather then the specific query.

Comment: The way you run direct SQL queries in Entity Framework is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/raw-sql).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run Common Table Expressions (CTEs) with LINQ. This is a provider-specific feature (although supported by SQL Server and Oracle) and therefore it is not supported.

Comment: That's not (strictly) true - for example, this CTE is just an alias for a sub-select, and that is easy to do in LINQ. Unfortunately `PARTITION` isn't.